# Ploting of acceptance, rejection and indecision of hypotesis testing

Tags: r, plot, hypothesis-test

I have two lists of p-values. I am testing the sign test for interval data. I have a list of 1000 pmin values and one list of pmax values. This p-values were calculated using values of M, which are 1000 values from -1 to 1.

Now, knowing that,if pmax < α then reject H0,
• if α < pmin then do not reject (accept) H0,
• otherwise (ie, if pmin ≤ α<= pmax ) then suspend the decision and, for example, demand more
observations to make a well‐based decision.

What I want is a plot like this:

[image]

That gives the acceptance in green, rejection in red and indecision in yellow.

I don't know how to plot this in R. I have tried but none of my plots are like this.

In the yaxis we have the p-values and in the xaxis we have the values of M.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create three new binary 0/1 variables (`reject`, `accept`, `indecision`) in your data frame corresponding to your definitions (you can use `transform()` from base R or `mutate()` from tidyverse). Then
overlay logistic regression fits, something like

```r
+ geom_smooth(aes(y = accept, x = M),
              method = "glm", method.args = list(family = binomial),
              color = "green")
```

should work for the reject and accept cases.  For the intermediate case you probably need to add `formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)`